# MySQL multiple select conditions in multiple tables in one query?

Tags: mysql, select, sql-order-by

I do not know where to start with this one, not sure if it is possible.

I have multiple columns. To simplify I will minimize my actual setup since I can describe it fine with two tables

Say I have two tables called thumbs & thumb_clicks.
What I need to do is select all of the most clicked thumbs and order by most clicked. My problem however is, what if only 2 thumbs were clicked and I need to display 100 on the page.

What I would like to accomplish is select thumbs by most clicked, if results are less than 100, select the most relevant thumbs to fill the rest of the spots.

I am looking to be pointed in the right direction for this if possible!
Appreciate it!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you looking for is `UNION` clause that lets you 'merge' results from two (or more) queries.

http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/union.html